# Docker Port mapping resulting in ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docusaurus

I have a web app that build markdown to react pages(docusaurus) I also have a python app to convert jupyter notebooks to markdown so that these can then also be converted to react pages.

I have now decided to containerize my solution and have run into a problem with port forwarding. When I start the container there aren't any errors but when I go to localhost:3000 which is where the react app should be I get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. Interestingly on other ports I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED so something must be working with the port mapping. I am running it with a fresh install of docker on macOS Montery 12.4 with intel chip.

*Dockerfile.frontend*

```
FROM nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.8-nodejs18
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 3000 8888
# Install python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/vega5-extension
# Install node dependencies
COPY package.json /app/
RUN npm install
# Build Markdown files from Jupyter Notebooks
COPY . /app/
RUN nbdoc_update && nbdoc_build
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  frontend:
    command: 'npm run start'
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.frontend
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
      - '8888:8888'
```

With `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP` I was also able to find out that the ports are listening:
com.docke 2921  ... TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
com.docke 2921  ... TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)

Comment: I would put my money on a web server virtual address/host binding. Take a lot on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184173/err-empty-response-from-docker-container

Comment: @OrelEraki Thank you so much this worked `npm run start -- --host 0.0.0.0`