# Why do I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when starting a react via docker?

Tags: reactjs, docker

I have such an app structure:

```
react-client
server
docker-compose.yaml
```

golang server normally starts in docker. And now I want to run react there. Here is my docker file for `react-client`

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app/react
COPY package.json /app/react
COPY package-lock.json /app/react
COPY . /app/react
EXPOSE 3001
RUN npm i
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:12
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '5432:5432'    
        volumes:
            - ./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - ./server/scripts/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
        env_file:
            - ./server/config/.env    
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "devdb", "-U","postgres" ]
            timeout: 45s
            interval: 10s
            retries: 10
    redis:
        image: redis:6.2
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock      
        ports:
          - 6379:6379 
    prometheus:
        image: "prom/prometheus:v2.21.0"
        ports:
          - "9090:9090"
        command:
          - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
        volumes:
          - "./server/metrics/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:ro"
    grafana:
        image: grafana/grafana:6.1.6
        environment:
          - GF_AUTH_DISABLE_LOGIN_FORM=true
          - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
          - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_NAME=Main Org.
          - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE=Admin
          - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
          - ./grafana/provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning
          - ./grafana/dashboards:/var/lib/grafana/dashboards
    web-client:
        build:
          context: ./react-client
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "3001:3001"
    app:
        build: 
          context: ./server
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
          - postgres
          - redis
```

And now when you start docker and when i go to `localhost:3001` i get an error:
`ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

And I can't figure out what's wrong.If I run docker without react and run it via `npm start` then everything works fine.
Maybe somehow not the whole project is copied?

**Edit**

I tried to do so

```
web-client:
        build:
          context: ./react-client
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "127.0.0.1:3001:3001"
```

but nothing has changed

I started the react separately on port 3000 and it starts fine.Apparently some kind of error occurs when starting on port 3001, but it is unclear what is wrong

Comment: Can you confirm node is running and listening in the container? From the node console/log.

Comment: @DanielW. After launching docker-compose, if i go to webclient inside container, it writes that it is listening on ```0.0.0.0:3001```. I don't know how else to proof

Comment: @Omegon exec into the web-client container and do `curl 127.0.0.1:3001` you might need to install curl first inside container.  Also to check your environment, run this `docker run --name gettingstarted -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started` see if you can see the the docker getting started page on your host machine localhost:80

Comment: @Omegon, can you post the `start` script in your `package.json` file?

Comment: is [this article](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/err_empty_response/) answers your question?

Comment: did you check if your docker file has an extension?

Comment: What are the logs from `web-client` seen with `docker logs` ? They may provide some info

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46203897/258174) is most likely your problem. Bind to `0.0.0.0` within your app, not `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Should the CMD be "npm", "start"?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to build an image for react-client and start a container manually.
First change your Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app/react
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3001
RUN npm i
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

- Then go into react-client directory and run `docker build -t test .`
- Start container: `docker run -d --name mytest -p 3001:3001 test`
- Check logs: `docker logs mytest`
- Check if the whole project is copied: `docker run --rm test ash -c "find /app/react -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t"`